# Series in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n \ge 0 $ for all n, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n\over 1+a_n}$ converges.

Here is my attempt!

=> Suppose that $\epsilon \ge 0$ is given and $a_n$ converges, then  for all $N\le n \le m$$$\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k \lt \epsilon.$$
let $b_n={a_n\over 1+a_n}$ and Notice that $b_n \lt a_n$ and

Then, applying the comparison test  $$|\sum_{k=n+1}^m b_k| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^m |b_k |\le\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k\lt\epsilon$$Hence,${a_n\over 1+a_n}$ converges.

let me know if it is worng and I don't know how to start for the other direction. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For $\implies$ just note $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n)\text{ converges}\implies \lim \limits_{n\to \infty}(a_n)=0\implies \lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_n\over 1+a_n}=0.$$ The other direction is false, just take $a_n=1$, for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Note, you have $\epsilon < \epsilon$.

Comment: The other direction is false but the question has if and only if statement.

Comment: maybe $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge  iff $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n\over 1+a_n}$ converge......

Comment: I edited the question and there were some typos.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** One direction is easy comparison.

For the other, suppose that $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges. Then after a while $a_n\le 1$. For such $n$, we have $a_n\le  \frac{2a_n}{1+a_n}$.

Comment: Thanks! so i guess what i did was right for the one direction.

Comment: Beatiful argument @AndréNicolas !

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the use of Comparison was the right thing for one direction. For both, actually, but the (long term) comparison for the other direction was a bit trickier.

Answer (score 2):

if $\sum a_n$ converge then $a_n\to 0$, so $a_n\sim \dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$, hence $\sum\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converge.

if $\sum\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converge, put $v_n=\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$, then $a_n=\dfrac{v_n}{1-v_n}$, as $v_n\to 0$ we have $u_n\sim v_n$ hence $\sum a_n$ converge.

Comment: Thanks! what about the way I approach to the first direction? is it still right? I know it was lengthy.

Comment: yes, the first direction is  right.